SQL scalar-valued function slow performance
I'm trying to optimize a query to remove the scalar valued function that returns a comma separated list example 'cor tag 1, tag test, testing, test.' I've read online that making it inline should benefit performance. Could someone please help with making my UserDefinedFunction inline or recommend how to improve performance?
-- Description: Returns a comma separated list of Tags for a defined Course Enrolment
--      
-- =============================================

/****** Object:  UserDefinedFunction [dbo].[fn_ConcatenateCourseEnrolmentTags] */
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[fn_ConcatenateCourseEnrolmentTags] (@ClientOfferRegID As int)  
    RETURNS nvarchar(3999) AS  
BEGIN 
    DECLARE @Desc nvarchar(3999)

    SELECT @Desc = IsNull(@Desc + ', ', '') + dbo.tbl_Tag_Shared.Name
FROM         dbo.tbl_Tag_Shared INNER JOIN
                      dbo.tbl_Record_Tag ON dbo.tbl_Tag_Shared.TagId = dbo.tbl_Record_Tag.TagId INNER JOIN
                      dbo.tbl_Entity ON dbo.tbl_Tag_Shared.EntityId = dbo.tbl_Entity.EntityId
WHERE     (dbo.tbl_Entity.ObjectId = '06') AND (dbo.tbl_Record_Tag.RecordId = @ClientOfferRegID)
ORDER BY dbo.tbl_Tag_Shared.Name
    
    RETURN @Desc
END

GO

        SELECT
                    tbl_Client.ClientID AS LearnerId, 
                    tbl_Client.FirstName AS LearnerFirstName, 
                    tbl_Client.LastName AS LearnerLastName, 
                    dbo.fn_ConcatenateCourseEnrolmentTags(tbl__Client_Offer_Reg.ClientOfferRegID) AS Tags,
        FROM        
                    tbl_Client
                    ...
        GROUP BY    
                    tbl_Client.ClientID, 
                    tbl_Client.FirstName, 
                    tbl_Client.LastName,
                    dbo.fn_ConcatenateCourseEnrolmentTags(tbl_Client_Offer_Reg.ClientOfferRegID),


FYI, using the syntax SELECT @Variable = @Variable + ... FROM is a documented antipattern and should be avoided; it relies on the data engine processing your data in a row by row order, which there is no guarantee of. Instead use string aggregation to achieve the same results. In recent versions of SQL Server that would be by using STRING_AGG, however, in older versions you'll need to use FOR XML PATH (and STUFF) to achieve the same results.

In this case, there really isn't any need for a scalar function either. Your outer query is already using aggregation, so you can just add STRING_AGG to that, as it's an aggregate function as well.

Yes it possible with subquery in SQL using function STRING_AGG
try below example.
SELECT
            tbl_Client.ClientID AS LearnerId, 
            tbl_Client.FirstName AS LearnerFirstName, 
            tbl_Client.LastName AS LearnerLastName, 
            ISNULL((select STRING_AGG(tbl__Client_Offer_Reg.ClientOfferRegID, ', ') 
                        from tbl_Client as ClientInner
                        where ClientOuter.ClientID = ClientInner.ClientID
                        And   ClientOuter.FirstName = ClientInner.FirstName
                        And   ClientOuter.LastName = ClientInner.LastName),'-') As Tags
FROM        
            tbl_Client as ClientOuter
            ...
GROUP BY    
            tbl_Client.ClientID, 
            tbl_Client.FirstName, 
            tbl_Client.LastName,


You could use the XML formatting feature (assuming you're using SQL server), it's quite commonly used for this:
SELECT ',' + ColumnName ... FOR XML PATH('')
You can find an example here:
What is the meaning of SELECT ... FOR XML PATH(' '),1,1)?
